# C 'for' loops in Ruby language

Tags: ruby

How can I express the next for loops in a rubysh way?

```
for (r = 1; r < R; r++) {
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            #do something
            }
}
```

I want to express the above code with an elegant ruby syntax.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would never use this. When it is absolutely necessary , i would use while loop since its the "mother" of all loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the way I'd write that in Ruby is this:

```
for r in 1..(R-1) do
  for i in 0..3 do
    # Do something
  end
end
```

But an even better way is to take advantage of the Range feature pointed out by @PedroNascimento in his answer, using three dots rather than two in order to leave the last item out of the Range:

```
for r in 1...R do
  for i in 0...4 do
    # Do something
  end
end
```

That's both nicer to look at and more clearly expresses the meaning of the code.

Answer (score 4):

```
1.upto(R-1) { |r|
   4.times {|i| 
      # Do something
   }
}
```

[RubyFiddle](http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/cb45f/1).

This is using the `Integer`'s [`upto`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Integer.html#method-i-upto) and [`times`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Integer.html#method-i-times) methods.

Comment: Note that this has two bugs in it and doesn't do what the loops in the question do (they each run one too many times).

Answer (score 1):

Just to keep things prettier: Ranges can also have three dots, excluding the last number. So the code would behave more closely if wrote like this:

```
for r in 1...R do
  for i in 0...4 do
    # Do something
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out; if I ever knew about three-dotted Ranges, I've long since forgotten.  I've incorporated this into my answer.

Comment: Awesome! This is one of the features I always mistakenly use the three dots, than remember you should use just two. As such, I see the three-dot behavior all the time! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    for r in 1..R-1
       for i on 0..3
          do something
       end
    end
```

[Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops.htm) you can find more syntax help for Ruby.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, but I'm not sure if that works as the original C code, for r in 1..R will be equivalent to for(r=0; r<=R; r++). Am I correct ?

Comment: initialize the value of "r" to 0 and it will work as same as you need.

Comment: My apologies. you can replace `R` with `R-1` and in the second `for` replace `4` with `3` .

Answer (score 0):

Just Another answer using [Range](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html#method-i-each).

```
r = 5 #
(1..r-1).each do|i|
  (1..3).each do |j|
       puts "i => #{i} , j => #{j}"
   end
end
```

This version inspired by @Pedro Nascimento 's answer.

```
r = 5 #
(1...r).each do|i|
  (1...3).each do |j|
       puts "i => #{i} , j => #{j}"
   end
end
```